# Remove start and end spaces in specific csv column

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to remove start and end spaces in column data in CSV file. I've got a solution to remove all spaces in the csv, but it's creating non-readable text in description column.

```
Get-Content –path test.csv| ForEach-Object {$_.Trim() -replace "\s+"   } |  Out-File -filepath out.csv -Encoding ascii
```

e.g.

```
'192.168.1.2'   ' test-1-TEST'  'Ping Down at least 1 min'  '3/11/2017' 'Unix Server'   'Ping'  'critical'
'192.168.1.3'   ' test-2-TEST'  ' Ping Down at least 3 min' '3/11/2017' 'windows Server'    'Ping'  'critical'
```

I only want to remove space only from `' test-1-TEST'` and not from `'Ping Down at least 1 min'`. Is this possible?

Comment: You need to post the header line of your CSV file and at least one line after that of sample data.

Answer (score 1):

```
"IP","ServerName","Status","Date","ServerType","Test","State"
"192.168.1.2"," test-1-TEST","Ping Down at least 1 min","3/11/2017","Unix Server","Ping","critical"
"192.168.1.3"," test-2-TEST"," Ping Down at least 3 min","3/11/2017","windows Server","Ping","critical"
```

For example file above:

```
Import-Csv C:\folder\file.csv | ForEach-Object {
        $_.ServerName = $_.ServerName.trim()
        $_
} | Export-Csv C:\folder\file2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Replace `ServerName` with the name of the Column you want to remove spaces from (aka `trim`).

Answer (score 0):

If your CSV does not have header (which means its not a true CSV) and/or you want to better preserve the original file structure and formatting you could try to expand on your regex a little.

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt -Raw) -replace "(?<=')\s+(?=[^' ])|(?<=[^' ])\s+(?=')"
```

That should remove all leading and trailing spaces inside the quoted values. Not the delimeters themselves.

Read the file in as one string. Could be bad idea depending on file size. Not required as the solution is not dependent on that. Can still be read line be line with the same transformation achieving the same result. Use two replacements that are similar. First is looking for spaces that exist after a single quote but not followed by another quote or space. Second is looking for spaces before a quote that are not preceded by a quote or space.

Just wanted to give a regex example. You can look into this with more detail and explanation at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/AzPEOR/1). There you will see an alternation pattern instead of two separate replacements.

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt -Raw) -replace "(?<=')\s+(?=[^' ])|(?<=[^' ])\s+(?=')"
```

The first example is a little easier on the eyes.

---

I was having issues consistently replicating this but if you are having issues with it replacing newlines as well then you can just do the replacement one line at a time and that should work as well.

```
(Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt) | Foreach-Object{
    $_ -replace "(?<=')\s+(?=[^' ])|(?<=[^' ])\s+(?=')"
} | Set-Content c:\temp\test.txt
```

Comment: It is working partially for me , everything is good except one thing . It is trimming next line space too so all output data is in single line . please suggest . I am running on 4.0 .

Comment: @sachinbhomale Sorry about that. I forgot about your comment. I made a small edit on the bottom that would work for this

Comment: Thanks Matt , its working for me but it is ignoring space at starting character .  
    ' 192.168.1.2' 'test-1-TEST''Ping Down at least 1 min''3/11/2017''Unix Server''Ping''critical'

Comment: @sachinbhomale That's unfortunate. I cannot replicate your issue using your sample text and adding leading spaces on the first "column" using my last edit. I used the regex101 link and added leading spaces there as well and it worked there as well.